# Add a shadow around BottomSheetDialog in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, dropshadow, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have designed a bottom sheet dialog which is using the entire screen width. This dialog is aligned bottom and have rounded corner on the top left/right part.

the layout is as below:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_rounded_corner">

        <TextView..
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The drawable is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/solidnight" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

it's look like this :

[image]

It's working but I need to add a shadow around now as shown in the image below:

[image]

I know the shadow could be tricky to see

Any idea how ?
thanks

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005714/how-to-show-shadow-around-the-linearlayout-in-android

Comment: Could you please try adding elevation to your parent layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

1.Define a custom style in your styles.xml file with the desired elevation:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
</style>
```

2.When creating your BottomSheetDialog, pass in the custom style:

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
```

This will apply a shadow with an elevation of 8dp around the BottomSheetDialog. You can adjust the elevation to your liking.

Note that this approach only works for API level 21 and above.
For API levels below 21, you can use the elevation attribute on a custom background drawable for the BottomSheetDialog.

You can refer to the following [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279689/how-can-i-add-a-shadow-to-bottom-sheet-view) post for more information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more modern and elegant way to implement it unless you
prefer not to use Material library. But if you do prefer, you will
benefit from its convenience. So you choose...
Here is two photos showing the end result both collapsed and expanded state.

[image: Bottom sheet collapsed]

[image: Bottom sheet expanded]

Well, if you'd like to implement in this way, you should be migrated your
project to *AndroidX* via the ***Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX*** menu option
in Android Studio and also have added the material library along with cardview
library in order to be able to build your project with the implementation that
I'll show next. So in your module's build.gradle file you shoud have the
following dependencies:

```groovy
dependencies {
    ...
    
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    
    ...
}
```

Next you wanna shape your bottom sheet with round corners but only the
top corners. To do this you need to add a `ShapeAppearanceOverlay` style in
your styles resource file as following:
**styles.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    
    <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.RoundCorners.Top"
        parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    </style>

    ...
</resources>
```

You can adjust each corner's value with this style and also you can use a cut
`cornerFamily` if you wish.

Next step is to implement the bottom sheet's layout. You can implement it
either independent to make it reusable or embedded to use it directly in your
main layout. I implemented as independent here. I used a `MaterialCardView` as
root element in order to be able to apply the `ShapeAppearance` and as well as
to control elevation more conveniently. Because the elevation is the key property
here to control the element's shadow.
**bottom_sheet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="16dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.RoundCorners.Top"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="OK"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:text="Bottom Sheet Example"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And finally you include the bottom sheet to your container layout. However note
that the bottom sheet's parent layout must be a `CoordinatorLayout` so that
it can behave with its bottom sheet behaviors.

**container.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After implementing everything properly you should see the same result as in the first 2 photos.